# Django : Foreign key set not found after saving object

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've got a question model and mcq choices model which have foreign key to question.

```
class Question(models.Model):
    statement = models.TextField(max_length=1024)
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Question,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
        #ques = Question.objects.get(id = self.id)
        f = open('/tmp/prj/log.txt', 'w')
        choiceobjs = self.choice_set.all()
        if choiceobjs:
           f.write("choices found")
        else:
           f.write("choices not found.. zilch")
        f.close()

 class Choice(models.Model):
    value = models.TextField(max_length=1024)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
```

Now I've overridden the save method of question. Even after the question has been saved, I cannot find choice_set in save method! I always get "choices not found.. zilch" in my logfile.

UPDATE: I'm creating my Question in Admin interface, and 'Choice' objects are being created 'inline'.

So the modified question is - In what sequence do the 'inline' fields/models and the main model get created? How can I delay my check for foreignkey set in save method, such that 'foreignkey_set' becomes visible?

Comment: Can you give an example how you are creating objects that lead to this error? I tested this and it worked for [this code](http://pastebin.com/8XCiVdez).

Comment: @Reiner - I'm using the admin interface for creating objects. I'll try the shell as well.

Comment: @Neo It does work in the admin too. As far as I can see, my example code is not much different from yours, so it must be something else. Is this all the relevant code on the models?

Comment: @Reiner - The whole code is a bit more complicated. But I'll post it.

Comment: @Reiner - The difference is that I'm creating those Choices "inline" in admin interface. Thats what is causing the problem. In the code you've mentioned, "save" method gets called even when first `f = Foo.objects.create()` statement gets called. At that point obviously there are no Bar objects in existence.

Comment: @Neo sure, but it does work in the end, when bar objects have been created. I didn't try this with inlines in the admin. Will do it now.

Comment: @Reiner - Just try your own code with f.write command logging as I've done. You'll find that after `Foo.objects.create()` command, the file will report "Not found".

Comment: @Neo You missunderstood me. Of course it won't work when I only create a Foo object. But before I can link Bar objects to a Foo object, I obviously have to create it first. This is not the problem. Once I've added 2 bar objects, and saved Foo, I could see these. You didn't mention that you used admin inlines. In that case, I can see the problem too.

Comment: @Reiner - Phew.. I thought I was doing something stupid :P. I guess I should start a different question on what is the sequence for inline creation of objects in Django.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    pass


class Bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
```

When using inlines of `Bar` in the `Foo` admin, Django has to save the `Foo` object first, because the `Bar` objects need the primary key to reference it in a `ForeignKey`:

```
self.save_model(request, new_object, form, change=False)
form.save_m2m()
for formset in formsets:
    self.save_formset(request, form, formset, change=False)
```

http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L870

That means when `Foo`'s `save` method is called, the inline `Bar` objects haven't been saved yet, and therefore can't be queried. So you need to work around this, if you need to access these objects when a Foo instance was saved in the admin (using Bar inlines).

One possible solution would be to attach to a `post_save` signal of `Bar`, see which `Foo` object it is referencing, and executing the relevant code. But this would trigger on every change, even if no Foo object was created.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I guess I'll just have to find a work around.